# How to you implements mongoTemplate.findDistinct()?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

Im trying to use the findDistinct function from mongoTemplate but i always retrieve an empty result list. 
Can you help me out to spot the problem ? Or maybe you have a simpliest way to do it

NB: 
I do have data in my collection
(on a basic find, i fetch more than 300 results in the list but all of this result are the same excepting on one key, i want all the distinct object from their NAME value for instance )

I tryied this :

```
List<DiffusionListImpl> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        query = new Query(Criteria.where("CUSTOMERNUMBER").is(1));
        list = mongoTemplate.findDistinct(query, KeyWhereIWantTheDistinct, collectionName,
                KlassResultModel.class);
    } catch (MongoException e) {
        logger.error("MongoException: " + e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error: " + e);
    }
    return list;
```

Comment: I made it work, but now on, the returning list contains the KeyWhereIWantTheDistinct instead of the model KlassResultModel

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i misread the documentation.

But i find it akward to have this kind of comportement of this function. 
I have to make a call to the DB to fetch a list of distinct value and then make another Call of the same DB to retrieve the object.

Is there any way to do it in one call? (Performance issue)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one DB call, use below code.

```
 final List<DiffusionListImpl> result =
        IteratorUtils.toList(this.mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName")
            .distinct("fieldName", query.getQueryObject(), DiffusionListImpl.class)
            .iterator());
```

for IteratorUtils you can use apache 
`import org.apache.commons.collections4.IteratorUtils;`